C program | how do compiler deal with the macro #define VAR(int) int
my test.c program is:
#include <stdio.h>

#define VAR(int) int

int main() {
    VAR(int)a = 0;
    printf("a:%d\n", a);

}

I expected to get a compile error, as the macro "VAR(int)a" should be extended to "inta". In fact the program compiled and ran without any error.
so, why the macro is extended as "VAR(int)a" => "int a", but not "VAR(int)a" => "inta"?
Here's the rusult in my system.
wu@PC-YLX47FF4:~$ gcc test.c -Wall
wu@PC-YLX47FF4:~$ ./a.out
a:0
wu@PC-YLX47FF4:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Per C 2024 6.10.5, preprocessor macro replacement does not substitute text; it substitutes grammatical tokens. Grammatical tokens include identifiers (like foo), some individual characters (like )), and some special combinations of characters (like <<).
By the time macro replacement takes place, the source text has already been processed into tokens, separating it at spaces and various special characters such as ). Macro replacement does not paste different tokens back together into adjacent text unless the pasting operator ## is used.
C 2024 5.2.1.2 specifies conceptual phases of translation (compilation, linking, and execution) of a program. Phases 1-3 process characters in various ways and create a sequence of grammatical tokens and white-space characters. Macro replacement occurs in phase 4, after the text has been formed into tokens.


I expected to get a compile error, as the macro VAR(int)a should be extended to "inta".

Your expectation is incorrect.   Just run the preprocessor alone with your source file and you will see how the preprocessor inserts a space in between.
The C standard requires that the macro preprocessor acts upon already tokenized language elements.  And so, you cannot use that trick (there's more on this) to join two tokens.  The preprocessor, when run alone  (this is, when run as a text macro processor), is enforced to insert a space in between both tokens, to frustrate any attempt you do to make them to appear as one token.
Ancient C compilers used a trick (invalid today, too) to do what you want, this is to add a comment between two tokens  (like int int_/**/a;, so when the C preprocessor eliminated the comments, both tokens got together (like you do) and so they are interpreted as one.  Today, you will see that all C preprocessors insert (at least) one space in those cases (in which a comment is surrounded immediately by two mergeable tokens) to avoid the merging.  For example, GCC inserts as many lines the comment used, and at least one space, to conserve line (and token) positions in the source to be the same in the preprocessed output.  This is important to do precise marking of error messages that cite the source code.
But, how to do that today?  Is it impossible? Not!!!  (but is limited, continue reading)
You can use a preprocessor operator ##, to join two tokens (of course, a test is done to check if they can be joined, see below) together.  It can be used only at macro expansion.  For example, if you want your variables to include their type in the name, so you can name a variable by mentioning its type, then you can use:
#define VAR(_typ, _nam)  _typ##_##_nam

that will expand
int VAR(int, a);

as
   int int_a;

(you will see that i have used the ## operator twice in the variable name, to separate both parameters from the underscore inserted in between)
But don't extend this too much, because you cannot use something like: VAR("int", a) to get neither "inta" nor inta, the compiler (and me) will not understand what you want to do with such a construction.
Also, you cannot do:
#define VAR(_typ) _typ##

because the ## operator REQUIRES two compatible tokens at both sides.  So, the token concatenation must resolve before the macro is completely expanded, avoiding to concatenate with something that has not been included in the macro expansion.  The compiler will receive an already created token with the concatenation of both.
Finnaly, check the standard for a precise idea of what a token is.  Tokens are basic elements of the language and so you must understand how the C text is divided into semantically valid basic units.
HINT:
If you want to know how the compiler expands some macro, you should know how to run the compiler preprocessor and get the output without also running the compiler.  There's normally an standard way to do this by using:
cpp mysource.c

but it is implemented normally by calling the compiler with some preprocessor only options, like in gcc:
gcc -E mysource.c

For example:
$ gcc -E - <<EOF  # - is used to represent standard input
> #define VAR(int) int
>    VAR(int)a;
> VAR("hello")world;
> EOF
# 0 "<stdin>"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"

    int a;
"hello"world;
$ _

(you will see in this sample above that the space is not inserted if the two tokens are not compatible ---this is, can be joined together without spaces)

A space is required after VAR(int)
VAR(int)a  => inta
VAR(int) a => int a


No, a space is not required.  Check it (and better, do it before posting).  The space will be inserted by the C preprocessor, check also the standard.

Learn something new everyday.  Thank you for the correction.

Glad to know.  :)
